# Trouble shoot a Haskell program

Tags: haskell

Can anyone tell me what is the problem with this Haskell program

```
import Control.Monad
import Data.Char

main = do  
    contents <- getContents  
    putStrLn $ contents  
    putStr $ "shortLinesOnly version is " ++ (shortLinesOnly contents)  
    putStr $ "printOnlyLessChars version is " ++ (printOnlyLessChars contents)
shortLinesOnly :: String -> String  
shortLinesOnly input =   
    let allLines = lines input  
        shortLines = filter (\line -> length line < 10) allLines  
        result = unlines shortLines  
    in  result  

--------------------the other way of doing this is -----------------
printOnlyLessChars contents = unlines $ filter (\a -> length a < 10)  $ lines $ contents
```

The program works fine, but it fails when I try to print the contents (line 5). Why is it having problems printing the string via putStrLn

The error message I get is

```
* Couldn't match expected type `(String -> IO ())
                                -> t0 -> IO String'
              with actual type `IO String'
* The function `getContents' is applied to one argument,
  but its type `IO String' has none
  In the expression: getContents putStrLn
```

Thanks,

Comment: Looks to me it is an indentation error: it things `putStrLn` is on the same line as `getContents`...

Comment: You have a tab character in your source code, making `putStrLn` be indented too much. Remove tabs, use spaces.

Comment: GHC should really warn for this. There's already an open [bug ticket](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/12610) for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the line that you need to focus on:

```
 In the expression: getContents putStrLn
```

This is haskell showing you how it views your code, but your code doesn't look like that.  This is almost always an indentation error.  Check that you don't have an extra space or a tab where it doesn't belong.

As a suggestion when reading haskell type error messages there are three places to look, and you should scan all of them before fixating on a single one:

- The type signature information -- do your types really match?
- The expression information -- does the expression the compiler sees match your expectations, or do you need to add `$` or parens
- Is there a typo or indentation problem.

I frequently feel my brain starting to overheat as I try to read through a really messy `Couldn't match expected type` so before I get too upset over trying to read that part of the error message I carefully check the `In the expression:` part to make sure that there is an easy to fix issue with how I entered the code.